# How to explode an array into another array and not subarray using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any possibility to explode values of an array to create direct a new array with these values. I'm able to do this only with a intemidiate step.

I have following array:

```
Array (
[0] => OtherMachines, Polymers
[1] => Engines/Pumps/Turbines, Measurement
[2] => Materials/Metallurgy
[3] => Materials/Metallurgy, ThermProcesses
)
```

Then I explode its values:

```
foreach ($array00 as $v) {
    $array01 = explode(", ", $v);
}
```

and receive following array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => OtherMachines
        [1] => Polymers
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Engines/Pumps/Turbines
        [1] => Measurement
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Materials/Metallurgy
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Materials/Metallurgy
        [1] => ThermProcesses
    )
)
```

Than I have to flatten the array to get the one I wish:

```
// Flatten the array.
$array02 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array01);
```

Final result:

```
Array (
[0] => OtherMachines
[1] => Polymers
[2] => Engines/Pumps/Turbines
[3] => Measurement
[4] => Materials/Metallurgy
[5] => Materials/Metallurgy
[6] => ThermProcesses
)
```

Is there any way to do this direct?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just implode it and then explode.

```
$result = explode(', ', implode(', ', $array));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array (
    'OtherMachines, Polymers',
    'Engines/Pumps/Turbines, Measurement',
    'Materials/Metallurgy',
    'Materials/Metallurgy, ThermProcesses'
);

print_r(array_map('trim', explode(',', implode(',', $arr))));

Array
(
    [0] => OtherMachines
    [1] => Polymers
    [2] => Engines/Pumps/Turbines
    [3] => Measurement
    [4] => Materials/Metallurgy
    [5] => Materials/Metallurgy
    [6] => ThermProcesses
)
```

http://codepad.org/h0n6NU3V

Answer (score 0):

Or simply:

```
$arr = array (
    'OtherMachines, Polymers',
    'Engines/Pumps/Turbines, Measurement',
    'Materials/Metallurgy',
    'Materials/Metallurgy, ThermProcesses'
);

print_r(explode(', ', implode(', ', $arr)));
```